# Dependency Injection in the ASP.NET 5 and Object Dispose

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

Can anybody help me to understand following in context to Dependency Injection in Asp.Net 5 and object dispose.

I need to understand if my Service implements `IDispose` interface ,who will call dispose method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IService, Service>();
    services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();
    services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();
    services.AddInstance<IService, Service>();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IServiceCollection contains the set of services available in your application. You defines the services you want to use and their lifetime, and the application will instantiate and dispose them for you.

There are 4 different lifetimes :

**Transient**

Transient lifetime services are created each time they are requested. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless service.

**Scoped**

Scoped lifetime services are created once per request.

**Singleton**

Singleton lifetime services are created the first time they are requested, and then every subsequent request will use the same instance. If your application requires singleton behavior, allowing the services container to manage the service’s lifetime is recommended instead of implementing the singleton design pattern and managing your object’s lifetime in the class yourself.

**Instance**

You can choose to add an instance directly to the services container. If you do so, this instance will be used for all subsequent requests (this technique will create a Singleton-scoped instance). One key difference between Instance services and Singleton services is that the Instance service is created in ConfigureServices, while the Singleton service is lazy-loaded the first time it is requested.

The asp.net 5 official documentation is great, take time to read it : http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html

---

The documentation doesn't mention how exactly the dependencies lifetimes are handled by the dependency injection service but if you search in the code, you will find the *ServiceProvider* class, who manages the lifetimes : [ServiceManager class](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs)

To be a little more specific, when a scope is created, the [service scope factory](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup/ServiceScopeFactory.cs) returns a new service scope, who is instanciated with a service provider. When the dependency injection service have to dispose a service, he calls the [service scope's dispose method](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceLookup/ServiceScope.cs#L22), who calls the [service provider's dispose method](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs#L143).

How the service provider works ? He has all the service scopes in a property, named *_resolvedServices*, and all the transiant disposables in a property named *_transientDisposables*. When the [dispose() method of the service provider](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs#L143) is called, he loops on all the items he has in this two properties, and for each object calls his *dispose* method.

You have all the source code here : [Dependency Injection source code](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/tree/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection)

Comment: Do the IService resource will be cleaned just like  what c# using statement does

Comment: Using statement defines a little scope of lifetime for object he uses, himself. Dependency Injection is a little different, and more complex because application can resolves a lot of things for you. For example, if you have a service who has a Repository in private property, repository who has your EF db context in private property, you have just to impements constructors with their needs, add each services in your startup class and the application will manage their dependencies for you. Anyway, the services will be cleaned when the application decide to, depends of the lifetime you gave them.

Comment: This is why the choice of the lifetime you give to each service is very important and needs to be considered.

Comment: Ok,  If I have IDbClient as service injected which closes and dispose IConnection  by implementing IDisposable interface. Now If I have injected as transient then after fulfilling Http Request and database work, my dbconnection will be closed and move to pool.

Comment: This answer describes when services are created. This question is when are they disposed. Who is responsible for the disposal? The DI framework or the code into which the services are injected? If the DI framework, how does it know when the service is no longer used?

Comment: It doesn't answer: It doesn't tell whether the dispose() method is directly called by DI framework.

Comment: @CharlesHETIER The documentation doesn't mention it but if you search in the code, you can find where that is the service provider who disposes the services with his dispose method : https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/4f2e6f035662b73936a2ed4fc249c163c9978c91/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs